# How to fire FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived from main activity?

Tags: android, firebase, service, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

For testing purposes, I would like to fire (programmatically from the main activity of my app) the onMessageReceived method of my MyFirebaseMessagingService class extending from FirebaseMessagingService. How can I do that ?

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {         
       // I would like to arrive here           
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean?
Fire onmessagerecived, or fire onmessagerecived programaticaly from mainactivity.

Comment: fire onmessagerecived programaticaly from mainactivity !

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What code is in there that you are trying to trigger? Can you put that code in a library/utility class, so that you can call it from both places?

Comment: Easiest way is honestly to just fire notifications from the Firebase console. Other than that, extract the code as @FrankvanPuffelen suggested and put it for example in a static method you can call.